# In javascript+flow, send a ?string into a function that expects a string

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I want to do `func3(MY_VAR)`, but `func3` expects a string, so just doing `func3(MY_VAR)` will raise a type error.

I am ok not running func3 if MY_VAR is undefind or null, but find using an if statement here very clumsy.

```
const MY_VAR: ?string = //Can be a string or undefined or null ....
const needToRunMulitipleFunctions = () => {
    func1();
    func2();
};
```

How do I do it elegantly without using a nasty if/else inside ?

Comment: MY_VAR && func3(MY_VAR)

Comment: That doesnt work. Flow complains of sketchy null check on MY_VAR which is potentiallly an empty string.

Comment: Ok then trueish expession && func3(...) , e.g. typeof var == "string"

Answer (score 0):

Because `MY_VAR` is maybe string and `func3` accepts a string only, you must do some kind of conditional type checking somewhere in your code. Otherwise your code is unsound and has potential bugs.

Here is a modification of your code to showcase your various options and how you may want to handle it.

```
let MY_VAR: ?string; //Can be a string or undefined or null ....

const func1 = () => {}
const func2 = () => {}
const func3 = (a: string) => {}
const func3WithCheck = (a: ?string) => {
    if (typeof a !== 'string') return;

    a.substring(0);
};

const needToRunMulitipleFunctions = () => {
    func1();
    func2();
    MY_VAR && func3(MY_VAR);
    func3(MY_VAR);
    func3();
    func3WithCheck(MY_VAR);
    //I want to do func3(MY_VAR), but func3 expects a string, so just doing func3(MY_VAR) will raise a type error. I am ok not running func3 if MY_VAR is undefind or null, but find using an if statement here very clumsy.
};
```

And here it is running in a try flow
https://flow.org/try/#0DYUwLgBAsgmg+gNQIICUBcED8BnMAnASwDsBzAbggHpKBhAQyIgCMQI6JdDSIB7PCAK5EAJiABmxEMN78iA4MAgA6FUoBQagMY8iuCGKGaAjBAC8EABQBKMwD4IAbwC+WnXoNFNAJjOWbp+2dXXUgPTQBmXws6DE5iEn9Al20Q-UNwgHUCMAALGhyQTQBrKJisONJExzUIWogCMUswAE8ABxAeRvYAQlNzAHIKkn6bPHABPCIyDTq2JWwBJiGLAAYraadp4L0iECkAFR4UISh5bIJW0AAxQzACNyiqhxq6sKNradmwrw+X2thEKgIAAyYFpTzhCwA5AodZ-cERKHwGFwr7pX5oiFZXL5QpFJGA2GfOrUACSEAA7gxIGAeBBhHSwpDoagrAAaZgCULpCAgAAe7U0YGwbA4+HiHOwdIAVgI9Az4gjmcjWZSCAoIHg6ARsKx2C12ry8Hg+EoIOS6ABbXglIg8SB4IRERVM+qNFkoeoioSiCQiGQQOQKDlMLn6YjSOWKhhusV0MAgS0gIiQApjCAANxAeGaEE0wAEluwzXUmyAA